# How to manipulate the input data using places.Autocomplete google api

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete

I'am trying to manipulate the input data using google.maps.places.Autocomplete. If the search retrieves an address with a place number, i want to change the input removing the number. For example, if the autocomplete results "Av. Paulista, 332, São Paulo, Brazil", i want to modify to "Av. Paulista, São Paulo, Brazil". How can i do that?

```
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);

    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
....
}
```

Thanks!